# How to make my iOS application handle web links

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

I have to make my application handel web like (juste like a web browser).
I add CFBundleURLTypes to my plist file and then in CFBundleURLSchemes I put http and CFBundleURLName com.mydomaine.myapp.
Then I tried to send a SMS with a web link : It's stil open Safari when I clicked the received link !

This work great with a custom schema : myapp://mylink.com ! but the problem is : I have to send SMS with links to my app users and then they can click those links and open myapp who do stuff flowing links contente ! the Message app dont recognize cutome url schema as a clickable link ! So the only solution I found is to make this operation using http link !

(I know that my problem can be solved using APN! but for some reasons I cant use it !)

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override http links to redirect to your app; that would break a lot of other pieces of the system.

You should send them a http link which goes to a server you set up. That server can then redirect the users to your custom link scheme, or offer to let them download the app, etc.